# How I save the history of my commands in Windows(7) Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I have realized that when I log out from the computer, the Command Prompt history gets deleted (or at least when I press the arrow keys (or F7) nothing appears. How I can set the command promt to not to delete my command history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an option to do so. However, you can use [clink](http://code.google.com/p/clink) which has that feature (although it comes with readline-style line editing and several other bash-isms that might not be wanted or needed).